# Starting from tomorrow vs From tomorrow on

Tags: word-choice

If we say something that will likely to continue everyday and it starts from tomorrow, how should we say this:

> Starting from tomorrow we will practice boxing at 5 o'clock.

or

> From tomorrow on we will practice boxing at 5 o'clock.

Which one would a native English speaker would choose or would be widely used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use one of these:

> **From now on**, we will practice at 5 o'clock.
>
> **Starting tomorrow**, we will practice at 5 o'clock.

The first one is a slightly idiomatic use of *now*.

Comment: While I appreciate you accepting this answer, I usually recommend waiting at least 12 hours (perhaps 24 is even better) before accepting an answer. Considering your question had only been active for two hours, a lot of our regular users hadn't even seen this question yet. I'd hate to have your acceptance of my answer dissuade someone from writing an even better one. So, from now on, perhaps you should wait until the next day, and see what kind of answers you might get before designating one of them as the most helpful.

Comment: J.R - the OP here most likely didn't notice your comment, we get notified only for comments made on our own posts. (or of course new answers to our questions)

Comment: @laruffii - Just in case you weren't alerted to my earlier comment, I'll leave this to trip a notification.